# Express js retrieve route callback function

Tags: express

In Express js, I register a route like this:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/user/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('user/new', {title: "Register"});
  });
}
```

How can I retrieve the callback function from that '/user/new' route, meaning to retrieve back the function below:

```
function(req, res) {
    res.render('user/new', {title: "Register"});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of a hack:

```
var handler = app._router.match('get', '/user/new').callbacks[0];
```